# Why were the comments deleted rather than moved to chat?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

The comments for the question [Why is the British government so determined to arrest Julian Assange?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/28319/why-is-the-british-government-so-determined-to-arrest-julian-assange) (the question itself, not the answers) were deleted, rather than moved to chat. I flagged a question asking if one of my comments could be undeleted, but I was declined ("declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention").

There wasn't any sign that comments had been moved to chat before, so it should have been technically possible to move the comments if the moderators wanted to.

Why were the comments deleted rather than moved to chat?

Answer (score 6):

Comments are [ephemeral by nature on the SE network](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3627/when-comments-are-flagged-are-related-comments-looked-at-by-moderators/3631#3631). They can get deleted without notice at moderators' discretion, for any reason. In particular when they're chatty or turn into an extensive discussion. If you'd like to post something whose nature is more permanent, post an answer.